# Error 'left side of interval must be <= right side' in pandas IntervalIndex

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| Volume code | from_date | to_date | Volume_1 | Volume_2 | Volume_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-01-01 00:59:59 | 8 | 4 | 7 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 01:00:00 | 2022-01-01 01:59:59 | 0 | 6 | 5 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 02:00:00 | 2022-01-01 02:59:59 | 10 | 9 | 14 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 03:00:00 | 2022-01-01 03:59:59 | 0 | 11 | 3 |
| 3 | 2022-01-01 04:00:00 | 2022-01-01 04:59:59 | 13 | 2 | 1 |

This dataframe is a pivoted table, which counts the ocurrences in each Volume code (Volume_x) in different time intervals. We have another table which has datetimes, and I need to know the number of ocurrences in the previous hour to that of the ancillary table.

For example, for a datetime 2022-01-01 03:16:43 in Volume_2, we would substract one hour, so 02:16:43, and look for it in the main dataframe, which would give us 9 ocurrences in that time frame. I did the following:

```
s = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df['from_date'] - pd.Timedelta(1, 'hour'),
                                 df['to_date'] - pd.Timedelta(1, 'hour'))
```

And it worked for a sample, but now I don't know why it raises the following error:

```
ValueError: left side of interval must be <= right side
```

As you can see in the table, `from_date` is always <= than `to_date`, so I cannot understand why is it failing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can test real data for greater values in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s1 = df['from_date'] - pd.Timedelta(1, 'hour')
s2 = df['to_date'] - pd.Timedelta(1, 'hour')

print (df[s1.gt(s2)])
```

Working same like:

```
print (df[df['from_date'].gt(df['to_date'])])
```